# data-table nested table should getting in proper format

Tags: jquery, datatables

[image]I've use data-table and create table in table for order receipt print for folowing table.
I want export that table in pdf and excel format. I've use following code of datatable

```js
var buttonCommon = {
  exportOptions: {
    format: {
      body: function(data, column, row) {
        data = data.replace(/<.*?>/g, "");
        return data;
      }
    }
  }
};
$('#example').DataTable({
  dom: 'Bfrtip',
  buttons: [
    $.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, {
      extend: 'copyHtml5'
    }),
    $.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, {
      extend: 'excelHtml5'
    }),
    $.extend(true, {}, buttonCommon, {
      extend: 'pdfHtml5'
    })
  ],
});
```

```html
<table id="example" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" >
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <table>
            <tr>
             <th>Franchisee Name:Abc</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Order No:123</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Address:Pune</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Order Date:02/03/2020</th>
            </tr>
          </table>
         </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
      <th>
         <div class="col-md-12">
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <td>Sr. No</td>
                <td>Product Name</td>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td>Amount</td>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>Pen</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>10</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
         </div>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

but children tables is not print in tabular format in pdf and csv. It should print in tabular format like look on screen. Is format of table is correct?. I've add screenshot of pdf format

Answer (score 0):

Does this table work for you?

```html
<html><head></head><body><table>
  <tbody><tr>
    <th>sr. No</th>
    <th>Product Name</th>
    <th>Price</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Pen</td>
    <td>5</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>Crayon</td>
    <td>10</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>20</td>
  </tr>
</tbody></table>
</body></html>
```

Comment: I don't want only product detail. I want print franchisee and order detail also in print so that I've created nested table for this. So that above table doesn't work for me